# pygame sys.exit() error after de-initializing modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
    def _check_keypresses(self, event):
        """Respond to key presses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and self.ship.moving_right == False:
            self.ship.moving_right = True

        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and self.ship.moving_left == False:
            self.ship.moving_left = True

        elif event.key == pygame.K.q:
            sys.exit()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keypresses(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyreleases(event)
```

`self._check_events()` is run in a main loop, listening for input. If the program is closed with `X` in the top right, the program exits normally. Once Q is pressed, sys.exit() follows, as well as an error right before the following error:

> *AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'K'*

Automatically, pygame will run `pygame.quit()` to de-initialize its modules before a `sys.exit()` is run. I believe it may have something to do with code being run after the modules are no longer in use, but before the program exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect.

```
elif event.key == pygame.K.q:
```

I believe you meant:

```
elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
```

Just a simple typo. Check the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html).